# Reading arrays from binary file: "read end of file" error

Tags: julia

I am reading/writing an array to file in Julia. For example:

```
test_arr=zeros(3,3)

io = open("logs/test","w")
write(io,test_arr)
close(io)
```

To read the file I do:

```
load_arr=Array{Float64}(undef,3,3)
io = open("logs/test","w")
read!(io,load_arr)
close(io)
```

This gives a "read end of file" error.

I am a bit perplexed as this is how I have been writing/reading other arrays to/from binary files without issue. But this time I get an error.

Comment: Changing `w` to `r` in the permissions of the `open` function before the `read` operation fixes it for me. This is a comment not an answer because I'm not certain why you're getting the error in the first place.

Comment: The error arises because opening with "w" will create the file if it doesn't exist, and *truncate the length of the file to zero* if it does. See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.open.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the problem is the result of a simple typo (opening the file incorrectly for reading).

Answer (score 1):

When opening the IOStream again, I think we want a read instead of another write:

```
io = open("logs/test","r")
```

For completeness from the comments above, opening a file with just `w` will truncate the file, so attempting to read from it will lead to an EOF error. More examples of what different modes do can be found here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.open

Comment: do you know why "w" works in other instances for reading. I don't know why I am getting the error only this time??

Comment: I believe that works in the other instance because you are writing, not reading. PaSTE gives a good answer for why you were receiving that error from before!